# Android Download Manger: download wont resume after failed with HTTP_DATA_ERROR

Tags: android, android-download-manager

When internet is OFF I see Android `DownloadManager` is doing 5 retries, in the 5th attempt it is showing `HTTP_DATA_ERROR`. After this, even if internet is ON download does not resume.

Below are the logs:

```
Line 2009: 10-09 12:27:26.795  2342  5380 D DownloadManager: [1701] Starting
Line 9895: 10-09 12:27:52.417  2342  5380 W DownloadManager: [1701] Stop requested with status HTTP_DATA_ERROR: Failed reading response: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: timeout
Line 9896: 10-09 12:27:52.419  2342  5380 D DownloadManager: [1701] Finished with status WAITING_TO_RETRY
Line 20736: 10-09 12:28:26.518  2342  5438 D DownloadManager: [1701] Starting
Line 20786: 10-09 12:28:26.646  2342  5438 W DownloadManager: [1701] Stop requested with status HTTP_DATA_ERROR: Unable to resolve host "c62d02045ba67b9fbb22ceb4bb32701f.cache.sko.fm": No address associated with hostname
Line 20787: 10-09 12:28:26.647  2342  5438 D DownloadManager: [1701] Finished with status WAITING_TO_RETRY
Line 45582: 10-09 12:29:45.793  2342  5478 D DownloadManager: [1701] Starting
Line 45742: 10-09 12:29:46.272  2342  5478 W DownloadManager: [1701] Stop requested with status HTTP_DATA_ERROR: Unable to resolve host "XXXXXXXX": No address associated with hostname
Line 45743: 10-09 12:29:46.273  2342  5478 D DownloadManager: [1701] Finished with status WAITING_TO_RETRY
Line 99591: 10-09 12:32:26.267  2342  5559 W DownloadManager: [1701] Stop requested with status HTTP_DATA_ERROR: Unable to resolve host "XXXXXXXX": No address associated with hostname
Line 99592: 10-09 12:32:26.269  2342  5559 D DownloadManager: [1701] Finished with status WAITING_TO_RETRY
Line 216529: 10-09 12:38:12.467  2342  5731 D DownloadManager: [1701] Starting
Line 216567: 10-09 12:38:12.586  2342  5731 W DownloadManager: [1701] Stop requested with status HTTP_DATA_ERROR: Unable to resolve host "XXXXXXXX": No address associated with hostname
Line 216568: 10-09 12:38:12.587  2342  5731 D DownloadManager: [1701] Finished with status HTTP_DATA_ERROR
```

- Getting `DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE` broadcast with status as `HTTP_DATA_ERROR`.
- Getting   DownloadStatus Paused when internet is OFF and finally getting   DownloadStatus Failed.

Is there any way to resume the failed download in `DownloadManager`?